# Сортировка по дате php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код. Берутся данные из table2 поля username и chislodata

Какой запрос сделать чтобы сначала списка показывало подледную дату?

```
<?php 
    $qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . table2)
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<table border="1">';
  echo '<thead>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th>Пользователь</th>';
  echo '<th>Датаth>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</thead>';
  echo '<tbody>';
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['username'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['chislodata'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</tbody>';
  echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: `"select * from " . table2." ORDER BY dateColumn DESC"`

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сортировка по полю column в порядке убывания

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` ORDER BY `column` DESC
```

сортировка по полю column в порядке возрастания

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` ORDER BY `column` ASC
```

Comment: А как из таблицы выводить последние 10 записей по полю id в котором нумерация идет автоматически?

Comment: SELECT * FROM 'tableName' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 10;

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все заработало.